# Help me to fix error getting at runtime

Tags: android

I'm new to android dev and i developed a sample proj named Math in that i created two windows one is entering the values and second one is to display the result. But the problem is when ever i entered the values and click on GO button it giving me some error. You can download my proj from link below:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=12A251B09B8A1A55&id=12A251B09B8A1A55!112&sc=documents#!/?cid=12a251b09b8a1a55&sc=documents&id=12A251B09B8A1A55!114

Thanks,

Comment: You might get a quicker response if you just posted your logcat and the code snippet for the go routines. Someone will probably help you out though

Comment: Hi, I already attached my code in the above link plz take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved your error,use the following two lines in your MathProjActivity

```
val1=Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput1)).getText().toString());
val2=Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput2)).getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
val1=Integer.parseInt(((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInput1)).toString());
val2=Integer.parseInt(((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInput2)).toString());
```

and use the following line

```
intent.putExtra("res",String.valueOf(res));
```

instead of

```
intent.putExtra("res",res);
```

Comment: Done. May i know where r u frm?